# Why has nobody ever been awarded Tenacious and Unsung hero on meta?

Tags: discussion, badges, zero-score-badges

Meta has been existing for about 5 years now and I looked at the badges today and noticed that nobody has ever won **Tenacious** and **Unsung hero**.

[image]

Why has nobody won these badges on meta?

Comment: That's because people on Meta are very generous with the votes. Either too many downvotes or too many upvotes! :) People asking questions here do upvote the answers they get. Hence, hardly 0-scored answered are accepted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because it is incredibly hard to post an answer on Meta that both gets accepted and also remains at a score of zero. In fact, out of the [98,000 answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer), there are only [800 such qualifying answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+isaccepted%3A1+votes%3A0).

Comment: And even most of those answers have **+1/-1** :)

Answer (score 4):

There are [59k questions on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions).

Of those, only [813 are 0 score and accepted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A0..0+isaccepted%3Atrue).

Nobody has unsung hero because just over 1% of accepted answers end up with zero score. By contrast, [SO has 6.2 million questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) with [713k having zero score accepted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3Atrue+score%3A0..0), for over 10% of the total.

Answer (score 0):

None of the meta StackOverflow users achieved that goal. This is the only reason for not awarding those badges.

In meta, most of the accepted answers got upvotes.